# WSO2 api manager analytics : CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address found executing

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In wso2 api manager analytics I faced following exception, could you please guide me?

```
Exception occurred :java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 172.24.64.114 found executing GET https://172.24.64.114:9443/api/am/admin/v1/custom-urls/carbon.super
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is failing due to hostname verification. Although you have relevant cert in the client truststore, you have used the IP address to communicate with APIM.

You have few options here.

1. Disable hostname verification (Not recommended for production)- https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/v3.2.0.2/docker-compose/apim-is-as-km-with-analytics/conf/apim-analytics-dashboard/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml#L25
2. Use the hostname instead of the IP. You can map your hostname with IP by adding a DNS entry or by adding an /etc/hosts entry. DNS entry is preferred for Prod

Comment: Thanks.  but after disable hostname verification, I get Status Code: 302 Found in analytics dashboard. colud you please guide me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345444/wso2-api-manager-3-2-0-analytics-302-found-status-code