# wso2 api manager 3.2.0 analytics 302 found status code

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to use wso2 api manager 3.2.0 analytics, but I get the following problem, could you please help me?

Wso2server ran in `172.24.64.114`

Worker and dashboard in `172.24.64.115`

[image]

dashboard config :

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:own apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:edit apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:view apim_analytics:business_analytics:own apim_analytics:business_analytics:edit apim_analytics:business_analytics:view apim_analytics:api_analytics:own apim_analytics:api_analytics:edit apim_analytics:api_analytics:view apim_analytics:application_analytics:own apim_analytics:application_analytics:edit apim_analytics:application_analytics:view
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://172.24.64.115:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443
    devPortalUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443
    externalLogoutUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443/oidc/logout
```

Comment: can you cross check your configs with https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/v3.2.0.2/docker-compose/apim-is-as-km-with-analytics/conf/apim-analytics-dashboard/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml?

Comment: Thanks. I checked but I have a question, wso2 api manager server ran in 172.24.64.114, so this should be as following : publisherUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443
    devPortalUrl: https://172.24.64.114:9443

Comment: I checked my config, every thimg is true, but I get 302 found status code